# Removing character data from numeric dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe that basically has its header recycled a couple of times, so it looks like this:

```
var1    var2    var3    var4
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
var1    var2    var3    var4
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
var1    var2    var3    var4
```

Most of the variables have numeric values; some, however, have character – so converting whole df into numeric won't help me. I was wondering how do I subset the dataframe to remove the re-appearing header? So, finally I would have this:

```
var1    var2    var3    var4
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
```

Comment: `df[df$var4 != 'var4',]` ?

Comment: and then use `df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert)`

Comment: Also, `df[!rowSums(df==names(df)), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the extra headers will have turned all of your data into factors (or character if you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`):

```
dd <- read.table(text="var1    var2    var3    var4
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
var1    var2    var3    var4
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
   1       1       1     'ch'
var1    var2    var3    var4")
```

Convert all but last column to numeric (ignore warnings):

```
dd[,1:3] <- lapply(dd[,1:3],
                    function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Throw away rows where the first three columns are `NA`:

```
dd <- dd[apply(dd[,1:3],1,function(x)!all(is.na(x))),]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
df[,1:3] <- sapply(df[,1:3], function(x) as.integer(as.character(x)))
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Comment: good but will cause problems if there are any other `NA` values in the data set ...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
rpts <- unique(as.vector(sapply(1:ncol(d), function(i) which(names(d)[i]==d[,i]))))
d <- d[-1*rpts,]
```

The first line extracts those rows in which the respective column name is appeared for all columns (i.e. `names(d)`). Second line accounts for deleting those extracted rows (i.e. `rpts`).

**data**

```
d <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("1", "var1"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "var2"), class = "factor"), 
    var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "var3"), class = "factor"), var4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("ch", "var4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```